# How do I convert string to date, compare by date and remove the result in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am currently trying to do these steps in MongoDB Query:
In the picture below there is commitDate or commitDate instant.

1-I want to convert this commitDate to date format

2-I want to compare this commitDate with a given date for example like:
{ $match: { date: { $lte: date, $gte: date }}}

3-I want to delete the results.

I know there is aggregation pipeline function $dateToString but I don't know how to compare and remove the documents in the range.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by remove the results? Do you mean you want to delete the documents that match the date range?

Comment: Yes, I mean that.

Comment: do you use spring data?

Comment: Yes If there is a way of doing that with spring data, I would like to hear it.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version 3.6 or greater of MongoDB, I would recommend using the [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator to convert the Strings in the database to to a date value before the comparison. It will make the comparison more accurate than trying to do so on Strings (in case there are bad values, e.g., "2020-13" is greater than "2020-01").

If you are using version 4.0 or greater, you can do something like the following. Note that the $dateFromString operation will make those dates that cannot be converted a null value and thus will not be matched by the $match operator.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: 
      {
        date2:{
          $dateFromString: {
              dateString: '$date',
              onError: null
          }
        }
      }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      date2:   {
        $gte: ISODate('2020-03-01T00:00:00.000'),
        $lte: ISODate('2020-05-01T00:00:00.000')
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(doc=> {
  db.dated.deleteOne({_id: doc._id});
  print(doc._id);
});
```

---

If you are using version later than 3.6 but earlier than 4.0, there is no onError parameter in the $dateFromString operator. So if you need to account for non-date values in the field, you'll have to filter those out before the conversion. Here is an aggregation pipeline matching dates by a regex. Regex may have to be changed depending on the date format of the field. (If you have no data issues, you don't need to worry about the first $match operation.)

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
     date: {$regex: /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\.\d{3}/} 
    }  
  },
  {
    $project: 
      {
        date2:{
          $dateFromString: {
              dateString: '$date'
          }
        }
      }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      date2:   {
        $gte: ISODate('2020-03-01T00:00:00.000'),
        $lte: ISODate('2020-05-01T00:00:00.000')
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(doc=> {
  db.dated.deleteOne({_id: doc._id});
  print(doc._id);
});
```